# impala support for arrays and maps

Tags: cloudera-cdh, impala

I am using impala 2.3 from cdh 5.5.1

From my understanding this version should support array and maps.

I have a table that has array field (please see below)

When I try to use the CLI to fetch this field I am getting:
Expr 'slots_available' in select list returns a complex type 'ARRAY'.
(Please see below)

Does impala 2.3 really supports arrays? Am I missing something?

Yosi

Server version: impalad version 2.3.0-cdh5.5.1 RELEASE (build 73bf5bc5afbb47aa7eab06cfbf6023ba8cb74f3c)

---

Welcome to the Impala shell. Copyright (c) 2015 Cloudera, Inc. All rights reserved.
(Impala Shell v2.3.0-cdh5.5.1 (73bf5bc) built on Wed Dec  2 10:39:33 PST 2015)

When pretty-printing is disabled, you can use the '--output_delimiter' flag to set
the delimiter for fields in the same row. The default is ','.

---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE olv_event.session (                
   event_id STRING,                                             
   ts BIGINT,                                                   
   slots_available ARRAY<STRING>                                
 )                                                              

 PARTITIONED BY (                                               
   dt STRING,                                                   
   hr INT                                                       
 )                                                              

 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format'='1')              
 STORED AS PARQUET                                              
 LOCATION 'hdfs://prod-hdp-master:8020/olv/event/session' 
 TBLPROPERTIES ('transient_lastDdlTime'='1460364027')
```

[prod-hdp-slave-1:21000] > select slots_available from start_session limit 1;
Query: select slots_available from start_session limit 1
ERROR: AnalysisException: Expr 'slots_available' in select list returns a complex type 'ARRAY'.
Only scalar types are allowed in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

You asked, "Does impala 2.3 really supports arrays?"

The answer is "yes, but not this usage of arrays."

[From the documentation:](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_complex_types.html#complex_types_queries)

> The result set of an Impala query always contains all scalar types;
>   the elements and fields within any complex type queries must be
>   "unpacked" using join queries. A query cannot directly retrieve the
>   entire value for a complex type column. Impala returns an error in
>   this case. Queries using SELECT * are allowed for tables with complex
>   types, but the columns with complex types are skipped.